# MYSQL Как выбрать значения которых нет у другой категории

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица:

```
id, lang_id, name, value
1    1       test    -
2    1       test2   --
3    2       test    ---
4    1       test3   ----
5    3       test4   -----
```

Как выбрать значения которых нет у lang_id 2. Т.е. это получается test2, test3, test4

Comment: А как выбрать строки у которых lang_id = 2?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

два варианта запросов, возвращающих требующийся набор данных из предоставленного примера:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0c8832/2)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
create table t (lang int, name text);

insert into t values
   (1, 'test')
  ,(1, 'test2')
  ,(2, 'test')
  ,(1, 'test3')
  ,(3, 'test4')
```

**Query 1**:

```
select name
from t where name not in (
  select name from t where lang = 2
)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0c8832/2/0)**:

```
|  name |
|-------|
| test2 |
| test3 |
| test4 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
select t1.name
from t as t1
left join t as t2
on t2.lang = 2
where t1.name <> t2.name
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0c8832/2/1)**:

```
|  name |
|-------|
| test2 |
| test3 |
| test4 |
```

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте так

```
select *
  from table t
 where name not in (
    select name
    from table
    where lang_id = 2)
```

Comment: А разве с полем `name` можно так делать (`IN`)? В смысле с полями, которые не численные.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский да можно